# Can Validator.TryValidateObject force [CustomValidation] attributes to validate a property?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have decorated a property of a class with a CustomValidationAttribute to validate if a GUID value was set but when I try to force it to be executed by using the helper method **Validator.TryValidateObject()** it seems that it doesn't invoke my validation logic.

The validation logic is being triggered when the value of the decorated property has changed, but I need to handle the scenario wherein the user clicks the save button without filling up required fields, hence the need to force validation attributes to run before a call to **DomainContext.SubmitChanges()** is called.

Interestingly, even classes that inherit from ValidationAtrribute isn't being run by Validator.TryValidateObject().

What is the correct way to force validation attributes to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom validators applied at the property level will have to be validated separately by using TryValidateProperty.

e.g.

```
Validator.TryValidateProperty(ViewModel.MyProperty,
                new ValidationContext(ViewModel.MyProperty, null, null) 
                { MemberName = "MyProperty" }, results);
```

Answer (score 1):

A more simplistic way of doing this is to set the last parameter (validateAllProperties) on TryValidateObject() to true. See the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more information.

```
List<ValidationResult> vr = new List<ValidationResult>();
ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(viewModel, null, null);
Validator.TryValidateObject(viewModel, vc, vr, true);
```